# Angular Filter by property OR another property

Tags: angularjs, filter

I've been trying to filter programatically an array using the angular filter `$filter('filter')`. I want to filter based in two properties, but i want that the result search in a property and/or another property.

Using this array

```
 [{
    id:1,
    name:'User2',
    rut:'22.222.222-2',
    created_at:'2016-03-23T18:36:34.404Z',
    updated_at:'2016-03-23T18:36:34.404Z',
    role_id:1},

  {
    id:2,
    name:'User1',
    rut:'11.111.111-1',
    created_at:'2016-03-23T18:36:34.416Z',
    updated_at:'2016-03-23T18:36:34.416Z',
    role_id:3}
];
```

When i search using the string "2016" i get the entire array because my filter search in **all the properties**, I need that if i search, looking in the properties `name` OR `rut`.

This it's my function that search:

```
vm.usersList = angular.copy(UsersResolve);

function search(_searchString){
   vm.usersList = $filter('filter')(UsersResolve, {$: _searchString})
                                  : UsersResolve;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)

The expression argument can be a `function(value, index, array) {}`. You can use this to filter out the array.

```
var searchString = '2016';
vm.usersList = $filter('filter')(UserResolve, function(value, index, array){
    if(value.name == searchString || value.rut == searchString) {
      return true;
    }    
  });
```

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0YthWGZ8lCQ6oj5sNfvu?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. You may be able to adapt it to $filter.

```
function search(_searchString){
   vm.usersList = vm.usersList.filter( function(user) {
       return user.name.indexOf(_searchString) >-1 || user.rut.indexOf(_searchString) 
   }
 }
```